# Is there a valid domain name guaranteed to be unreachable?

Tags: http, testing

Is there a valid domain name used by convention for test cases where the host is supposed to be unreachable? E.g. http://www.unreachable.net/ or http://www.downforever.net/ which seem to be down right now - but for how long?

Or at least an IP address guaranteed to be unreachable? (The Special-Use IPv4 Address spec https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3330 does not seem to mention such an address).

<s>UPDATE: The top-level domain *invalid* in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606 comes close (thanks JOTN), but I'm looking for a domain that can be resolved to an IP which is not reachable (i.e. no server responds).</s>

Comment: If you own your own domain, you could also decide to never create a certain sub-domain such as `invalid.example.com` (`example.com` and all its sub-domains may respond, but using your own domain, you could make sure that you never define that sub-domain).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you mean by valid?  There's the reserved top level domain: example, invalid, localhost, and test.

It talks about those here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain#Reserved_domains

Answer (score -1):

http://localhost:31337, maybe?

Comment: @AalokParikh: So, what exactly is it that you're doing? Looking at your recent activity, it seems the answer might be "randomly commenting on answers without considering the context of the answer with respect to the question."

Comment: It's not just like that. I try to do my best to understand the context first and then give the comment but yes some times only the link will force me to just click and delete option as so many answers just have only links sorry for my misunderstanding :)